# How does wsgi handle multiple request headers with the same name?

Tags: python, http, wsgi

In WSGI headers are represented in the environ as 'HTTP_XXX' values. For example the value `Cookie:` header is stored at the `HTTP_COOKIE` key of the environ.

How are multiple request headers with the same header name represented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple cookies are combined into a single header, separated by semicolons.

Multiple headers are allowed by [the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), but only for certain kinds of headers, and it is always permissible to combine those headers into one (though using commas, not semicolons)

Answer (score 3):

I thought the answer to this one would be trivial, but after digging a bit I'm not so sure.

Here's what I've found so far:

The WSGI PEP-333 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) suggests that the environment variables should contain whatever the CGI specification says.

The CGI specification (getting harder to find, a lot of broken links, best I could find at [draft-coar-cgi-v11-03](http://ken.coar.org/cgi/draft-coar-cgi-v11-03-clean.html#6.1.5)) talks about metadata and says (section 6.1.5)

> ". If multiple header fields with the
>   same field-name are received then the
>   server MUST rewrite them as though
>   they had been received as a single
>   header field having the same semantics
>   before being represented in a
>   metavariable"

Which suggests to me that if you have multiple header lines with the same key, you must join them up somehow into one line.

HTTP_COOKIE, as an example, supports this by concatenating all the key=value pairs into one line with semicolons between them.